# How can i make my recyclerview translucent

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to make a fragment for search view , where i want my recycler view to be translucent ( the whole view ).

Something like this :
[image]

i tried changing the alpha , but it did not help much ! suggestions on what can be done ?

Comment: Add a View Over It with translucent background color. make the View  clickable if you want to block recyclerView click otherwise just use it as it is

Comment: How did it look when using alpha? I don't understand how that didn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out !!

I added a empty view on top of the reyclerview , with a background colour & alpha of 0.1

also changed the alpha of the recycler view to 0.5

**Adding the extra empty view was the key that i was missing**

Answer (score 0):

Just set the background colour of your recycler view to transparent colour value.
**Transparent hex code: #00000000**

And if you want it to be translucent then, try using the colour picker of android studio and change the opacity accordingly to get your desired transparency.

Answer (score 0):

> Adding the extra empty view was the key that i was missing

I think so too. It is a good and simple way.